# Rails 4: Why does my content attribute return undefined after refactoring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, attributes

I have a simple search setup that uses the twitter gem api to fetch and save some tweets if a search term is given. Here is my `index` action in my `HomeController` that works perfectly well.

```
  def index
    Tweet.pull_tweets_from_search(params[:term]) unless params[:term].blank?
    @tweets ||= Tweet.latest
    @terms = Tweet.terms
  end
```

Tweets get saved and fetched. My code works.
But I am not happy with this and want to refactor it thus:

```
  def index
    @tweets ||= params[:term].blank? ? Tweet.latest : Tweet.pull_tweets_from_search(params[:term])
    @terms = Tweet.terms
  end
```

But this now gives me an error:

```
undefined method `content' for #<Twitter::Tweet:0x007fd2b30bcc90>
```

On the model side, I have a concerns class that has the `pull_tweets_from_search` method:

```
    module ClassMethods
        def pull_tweets_from_search(term)
            if term
                search_and_add(term)
            else
                latest
            end
        end
    end
```

`latest` happens to be a scope that looks like this in my model class `tweet.rb`:

```
scope :latest, ->{ order("created_at desc").limit(6) }
```

The strange thing is that the tweet does get saved with the *content* attribute. It only seems to choke on the template where the content variable appears:

```
<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
    <blockquote>
        <em><%= parsed_text(tweet.content)  %></em>
        # ---
```

**UPDATE**
The actual code to fetch and save tweets looks like this:

```
         def search_and_add(term)
        Twitter.search(term, :lang => "en", count:5).results.each do |tweet|
            unless exists?(tweet_id: tweet.id)
                        create!(
                            term: term,
                            tweet_id: tweet.id,
                            content: tweet.text,
                            screen_name: tweet.user.screen_name
                        )
            end
           end
        end
```

What is going wrong here when I refactor? Why am I getting this error when the attribute *does* exist?

Comment: What happens if instead of `parsed_text(tweet.content)` you just put `tweet.inspect`? Does it show content as an attribute then?

Comment: Ya just tried that - the problem is I am getting tweets from the twitter api instead of the database when I refactor.

Comment: I should put this as an answer....

Comment: @bgates How could I refactor the `search_and_add` method to return tweets with my database fields?

Answer (score 0):

the `||=` operator tales precedence over the `? :` operator. See http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#table_18.4

Add parenthesis, like this:

```
def index
  @tweets ||= (params[:term].blank? ? Tweet.latest : Tweet.pull_tweets_from_search(params[:term]))
  @terms = Tweet.terms
end
```

Comment: this does not work. The problem is that when I refactor, I end up getting tweets from the twitter api rather than my database. See my updated code for fetching tweets please.

Answer (score 0):

In your `search_and_add`, `Twitter.search.results` returns a set of objects that have #text, not #content. It doesn't matter that you're creating proper tweet objects within the #each block, when you finish enumerating the return value is the collection of things with #text.

To get that method to return the sort of objects you want,

```
def search_and_add(term)
  Twitter.search(term, :lang => "en", count:5).results.map do |tweet|
    where("tweet_id = ?", tweet.id).first ||
    create!(
      term: term,
      tweet_id: tweet.id,
      content: tweet.text,
      screen_name: tweet.user.screen_name
    )
  end
end
```